# Conservative vector fields on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Given a vector field on a Riemannian manifold $M$, is there a condition that ensures the existence of a potential $\psi\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $\nabla \psi=X$?

Something like $\text{curl}(F)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can assume $M$ compact and connected.

Comment: Not much can we say, unless $M$ is simply connected.

Comment: And if it is the case?

Comment: If that's the case then it is  equivalent to $curl (X) = 0$.

Comment: It might be helpful to use the metric to change this to a question about $1$-forms, rather than vector fields. Then you need $H^1(X)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Riemannian metric $g$ is non-degenerate, it induces an isomorphism $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M) \mapsto X^\flat\in\Omega(M)$ given by
$$
X^\flat(Y) := g(X,Y).
$$
The potential condition can be written as $X^\flat = d\psi$. This is true locally if $dX^\flat = 0$. It's true globally if in addition $H^1(M) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.